# How to limit End Time to within +8 hours?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, calendar

I am trying to limit the End Time of a Calendar Event to be within +8 hours of the creation time.

I've used this formula `=AND([End Time]>=TODAY(),[End Time]<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+2,DAY(TODAY())))` to limit the End Time to +2 months from the creation date, but can't get something similar to work in regards to Hours.

Comment: ``NOW()`` gives you the time info you want

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using list validation (not column validation).  I used this formula:

```
=AND([End Time]<=([Created]+TIME(8,0,0)),[End Time]>[Created])
```